# pandas dataFrame's replace gives NaN values

Tags: python

I have df with string values of 'right' and 'left which I need to convert to 1s and 0s. After converting column's type to numerical I tried to use pandas replace method but the result was NaN values.
The code
I wrote is as follows:

```
right_hand[' Hand Type'].replace({'right':1, 'left':0})
```

The result is:

```
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
    ..
4423   NaN
4424   NaN
4425   NaN
4426   NaN
4427   NaN
Name:  Hand Type, Length: 4428, dtype: float64
```

How can I solve this? what am I doing wrong?

original dataFrame:

```
Time    Frame ID    Hand Type   # hands  

0   343.0061    129364  right   2   
1   343.0392    129367  left    2   
2   343.0889    129373  right   2   
3   343.1220    129377  left    2   
4   343.1720    129383  right   2
```

result:

```
Time    Frame ID    Hand Type   # hands  

0   343.0061    129364  NaN     2   
1   343.0392    129367  NaN     2   
2   343.0889    129373  NaN     2   
3   343.1220    129377  NaN     2   
4   343.1720    129383  NaN     2
```

Comment: Show us the original dataset

Comment: Add the original DataFrame to the question. You might check, there is a space before the column name(Hand Type) if that is intended.

Comment: Print the column names and show us.  Maybe there is no space for column Hand Type

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [document](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) from Pandas. Maybe you use the wrong way of `replace` function

```
import pandas as pd
right_hand = pd.DataFrame({'Hand_Type': ['left', 'right', 'right', 'left']})
print(right_hand)
```

If you want to convert 'left' -> 0 and 'right' -> 1. This should be

```
right_hand = right_hand.replace({'Hand_Type':  {'right':1, 'left':0}})
print(right_hand)
```

Result:

```
  Hand_Type
0      left
1     right
2     right
3      left
   Hand_Type
0          0
1          1
2          1
3          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Without (sample) data I cannot reproduce the exact result with the `NaN` values. However, is it correct that the column names starts with a space character?

You can add `inplace = True` to replace the values in the column.

```
import pandas as pd
right_hand = pd.DataFrame({'Hand Type': ['right', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left', 'left']})

right_hand['Hand Type'].replace({'right':1, 'left':0})
print(right_hand['Hand Type'])

right_hand['Hand Type'].replace({'right':1, 'left':0}, inplace=True)
print(right_hand['Hand Type'])
```

Result(s):

```
0    right
1    right
2     left
3    right
4     left
5     left
Name: Hand Type, dtype: object

0    1
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
Name: Hand Type, dtype: int64
```

As an alternative. you can use `map`:

```
right_hand['Hand Type'].map({'right':1, 'left':0})
```

Comment: Great to hear that the map method worked for you! Can you accept the answer? Thanks in advance.